# Map coordinates of an element in an image by knowing only the resolution - Android

Tags: android, image, draw, shapes

I'm trying to develop an Android app to recognize if a user is drawing inside a shape. This is an example: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fguh.jpg
I know that the picture resolution is 512x512, how can I get and specify the range of coordinates of that shapes? Is it possible to get them by the resolution? This is my drawing app:

```java
public class DrawingView extends View {

    public int width;
    public  int height;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
    Context context;
    private Paint circlePaint;
    private Path circlePath;

    public DrawingView(Context c) {
        super(c);
        context=c;
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        circlePaint = new Paint();
        circlePath = new Path();
        circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        circlePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
        circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
            circlePath.reset();
            circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
        }
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath,  mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I was thinking to check it manually by loading the image and checking it manually, but since it has not a shape like a square or a rectangular its impossible to define a range like (from x to y...)